# Context.User.Identity.Name changes from one postback to the next

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running an ASP.Net (C# 4.7.2) application. In the master page code behind, I am capturing the value of Context.User.identity.Name in a ViewState variable. In one call Context.User.identity.Name comes back with my domain and username. In a subsequent call, Context.User.identity.Name is coming back with my last name, first name. Why is it changing from one call to another?

```
If (!IsPostBack)
{ Viewstate[myvar] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty; }
else
{ if (string)ViewState[myvar] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty)
{ throw new Exception("Not the same person");}
```

}

In the some calls, I will get mydomain\myusername from Context.User.identity.Name and then it shifts to Smith, John.

At least within the same session, shouldn't Context.User.identity.Name always come back with the same value? I don't really care which one it comes back with, I just want it to always be the same value.

Comment: Is there a pattern to it, or seemingly random? It seems like some sort of interaction with your identity provider. Maybe it's getting normalized after the first interaction or something? Just some thoughts...

Comment: The only pattern is that it is happening on a post back from one specific page. Where it sets the viewstate variable with the username and then on the postback from that page it switches to actual name. I've seen it happen where the page load is my actual name (instead of my username), but the postback also has my actual name (I haven't noticed a pattern with that yet). So that is ok (not great) because it won't throw the error. I find it odd that it changes at all.